# Trying to style this button responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image]

I'm trying to style this button responsively, but I know i'm not doing it great because when I shrink or expand my browser it either breaks, or the text gets pushed off to far to the right, and it doesn't stay centered.

I also believe I using way too many media queries than I need to, which is why I believe there has to be a better way of building this.

Here's the code I have now:

```css
.appt-btn-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background: #fa6304;
  width: 100%;
}

.appt-btn-container a {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.appt-btn-container:hover a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.appt-btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  line-height: 117px;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.appt-btn-container .calendar-icon {
  background: #d35302;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 26px 20px 25px 22px;
}

.appt-btn-container .calendar-icon .calendar-icon-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #d35302;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  right: -14px;
}

 @media (min-width:1200px) and (max-width:1350px) {
    .appt-btn {
       font-size: 22px;
    }
 }

@media (min-width:1351px) and (max-width:1480px) {
   .appt-btn {
      font-size: 26px;
      margin-left: 175px;
   }
 }

 @media (min-width:1481px) and (max-width:1625px) {
    .appt-btn {
       font-size: 29px;
    }
 }

@media (min-width:1626px) and (max-width:1775px) {
   .appt-btn {
     font-size: 33px;
   }
}

@media (min-width:1700px) {
   .appt-btn {
      margin-left: 180px;
   }
}

@media (min-width:1776px) {
   .appt-btn {
      font-size: 35px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="appt-btn-container">
  <span class="calendar-icon">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://flying-saucer.s3.amazonaws.com/calendar-icon-white-1.jpeg">
    <span class="calendar-icon-arrow"></span>
  </span>
  <a href="/contact-us/" class="appt-btn">
    Call For Free Estimate
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are you ok with restructuring the HTML? can you please give the full path the the image so we can work with it?

Comment: easiest solution would be to give the `.appt-btn-container` a min-width to the point where it not breaks.

Comment: @tacoshy i added a png i scraped off the web for quick use, so it doesn't appear perfect but i think it'll work for these purposes. Thanks for the help. I'll try the min-width approach